# Lua. look for an associated (with MAC) IP in dhcp.leases

Tags: parsing, lua

I am looking for a Lua replacement for the following bash script:

```
MAC="d4:be:d9:3a:78:88"
IP=`grep $MAC /tmp/dhcp.leases | awk {'print $3'}`

echo $IP
```

/tmp/dhcp.leases looks like:

```
1497518739 d4:be:d9:3a:78:88 192.168.96.180 DESKTOP-2VECMJ7 01:d4:be:d9:3a:78:88
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the file into a Lua string, extracting the IP address is simple:

```
function extract(text,mac)
  return text:match(" "..mac.." (.-) ")
end
```